# Can we install a package through a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, apt, sudo

I'm trying to write a shell script so that when I reinstall my Ubuntu again. I could just run script and retain all the packages. And I'm planning to pass password in form of argument.

My question here is how can i enter into `sudo` domain without manually entering password. As I'm also planning to design a UI where it can't access the terminal there.

**Ex:**

```
./recover.sh password
```

Comment: If you're in a recovery zone you may not even have `sudo`. Have you considered just using backup tools that provide bare-metal restore?

Comment: No actually I'm trying to build myself a `recovery tool`.

Comment: Just eager if its possible!

Comment: You can configure `sudo` to avoid requiring a password (read up on the `NOPASSWD` attribute). But if you're in a recovery zone then I don't see how you would have the modified configuration file necessary for this to happen - you'd need to be root to change the configuration file, in which case you might as well run the entire script as root and avoid `sudo` entirely.

Comment: I got the answer `echo password | sudo ./recover.sh`

Comment: this ll let us pass the password through argv

Comment: @Pavan If you found a solution you can just post it as an answer an accept it (although piping the password to sudo like that definitely doesn't work)

Comment: @John have you tried this and do you find it works (test with the `id` command to see which uid is running your code)

Comment: @John do you find setuid scripts work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use...

```
echo password | sudo -S recover.sh
```

Password being your sudo password.

From sudo manpage..

> -S, --stdin
>   Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.

And second method is

```
sudo -S <<< password apt-get install pkg_name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to enter password manually you use `-A` option of `sudo`

> ```
>  -A, --askpass
>              Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's
>              terminal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphi‐
>              cal) helper program is executed to read the user's password and output
>              the password to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment
>              variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper program.
> ```

**How to use it?**

1. make a file which will contain your password (unencrypted):

   ```
   cat .pass
   #!/bin/bash
   echo password
   ```
2. Now set it permissions to only executable by only you:

   ```
   chmod u=x,go= .pass
   ```
3. now the actual usage

   ```
   SUDO_ASKPASS="~/.pass" sudo -A <command>
   ```

This way you can run any command as **root** without entering password

*I wouldn't recommend you to store your password unencrypted on your computer, it is very unsafe.*

Comment: actually I'm planning to pass the `password` through argument.